# Adding items to a webuser control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webuser control to all users in the role of Staff. However the user control has some links to other pages too.The problem is that when a student logs in.He can see some admin pages whereby I need him to only view different  hyperlink.How can I add items so as the students can only see links of their own than being able to view admin pages?

Below is my code

```
LoginView control = (LoginView)Master.FindControl("LoginView1");
var con= (StudentsPanel)control.FindControl("StudentsPanel");
if (con!= null)
{
//This is= where i need to load the new items and show them to a student
}
```

I need to change the links in the StudentsPanel since its in a panel and i dont want them to view the links on it but initiate new links..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why "modify" the links? Have two panels, one for Admins, one for Students.. and depending on who is logged in, hide the one panel?